# What does clf mean in machine learning?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

When doing fitting, I always come across code like

```
clf = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

(from http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#k-fold)

What does `clf` stand for? I googled around but didn't find any clues.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In the [`scikit-learn` tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#learning-and-predicting), it's short for classifier.:

> We call our estimator instance `clf`, as it is a classifier.

Answer (score 6):

In the link you provided, clf refers to classifier.

Answer (score 0):

You can write svm_model or any easy name at place of of clf for better understanding.